# Failed to set remote answer sdp: Failed to apply the description for m= section with mid='0': Failed to set SSL role for the transport

Tags: javascript, webrtc

So this is how my code works
Peer A will join the room and when Peer B joins the same room

- Peer A will send an offer to Peer B
- Peer B will send an answer to Peer A
- Peer A will send ice candidates to Peer B
- Peer B will send ice candidates to Peer A

so the error is happening while peer B is setting the received offer to its remote description
and then the whole cycle begins, it turns into a loop from step 1.

Does anyone know why it happens, i am facing it while using any browser.

Edit: Followed Biju Kalanjoor's answer and implemented signaling in the perfect negotiation way and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

IceGathering is a parallel process, Also you should check [Jan-Ivar Bruaroey Perfect Negotiation](https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/perfect-negotiation-in-webrtc/)

This will clear your queries.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the article, followed it and it's working.

Comment: you are not answering the question